# Bootstrap 3 col equal height with dynamic and uneven content

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make `col-*-3` equal height where the content inside `col's` are dynamic and uneven.

CSS

```
.quotebox {
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #5B5B5B;
}
.comp-logo {
    width: 90%;
    padding: 0px 30px 10px 30px;
}
.choices h4 {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #5B5B5B;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    color: #fff;
}
.btn-booking {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 6px 6px;
}
.order-btn {
    /* position:absolute;  */
}
```

HTML

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="equalHeight">
        <div class="col-sm-3 choices">
            <div class="quotebox">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <h4>Heading Title</h4>
                        <img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/110328/screenshots/1666562/flat_icons_1x.png" alt="logo" class="comp-logo" />
                        <p>uneven content uneven content uneven content uneven content uneven content uneven content uneven content uneven content uneven content uneven content uneven content uneven content uneven content uneven content uneven content uneven content unev</p>
                        <div class="more-info text-center"> <a class="btn btn-primary">More Information</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <h5>Todays Price</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <h5>&pound; 100</h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="order-btn text-center">
                            <form action="#" method="post">
                                <input type="submit" value="Book Book Book" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-booking" />
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 choices">
            <div class="quotebox">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <h4>Heading Title</h4>
                        <img src="http://cdn.freebiesbug.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/flat-icons.jpg" alt="logo" class="comp-logo" />
                        <p>uneven content uneven content uneven content uneven content uneven content uneven content uneven content uneven content uneven content uneven content uneven content uneven content uneven content uneven contentuneven content uneven content unevuneven content uneven content unevuneven content uneven content unev</p>
                        <div class="more-info text-center"> <a class="btn btn-primary">More Information</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <h5>Todays Price</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <h5>&pound; 100</h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="order-btn text-center">
                            <form action="#" method="post">
                                <input type="submit" value="Book Book Book" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-booking" />
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 choices">
            <div class="quotebox">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <h4>Heading Title</h4>
                        <img src="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/x/business-flat-icons-set-web-mobile-design-application-35047525.jpg" alt="logo" class="comp-logo" />
                        <p>uneven content uneven content uneven content uneven content uneven content uneven content uneven content uneven content uneven content uneven content uneven content uneven content uneven content uneven contentuneven content uneven content unev</p>
                        <div class="more-info text-center"> <a class="btn btn-primary">More Information</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <h5>Todays Price</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <h5>&pound; 100</h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="order-btn text-center">
                            <form action="#" method="post">
                                <input type="submit" value="Book Book Book" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-booking" />
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 choices">
            <div class="quotebox">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <h4>Heading Title</h4>
                        <img src="http://flatdsgn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Free-Retina-Flat-Icons2.jpg" alt="logo" class="comp-logo" />
                        <p>uneven content uneven content uneven content uneven content uneven content uneven content uneven content uneven content uneven content uneven content</p>
                        <div class="more-info text-center"> <a class="btn btn-primary">More Information</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <h5>Todays Price</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <h5>&pound; 100</h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="order-btn text-center">
                            <form action="#" method="post">
                                <input type="submit" value="Book Book Book" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-booking" />
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried

- `display:table`, makes it non-responsive
- Don't want to use `display:flex` due to lack of mobile browser support
- Tried following jQuery script

  ```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#equalHeight").each(function () {
      var highestBox = 0;
      $(".quotebox", this).each(function () {
          if ($(this).height() > highestBox) highestBox = $(this).height();
      });
      $(".quotebox", this).height(highestBox);
    });
  });
  ```

with jQuery, the col's height will be equal but the `book` button will not stick at bottom, `position:absolute;` also didn't work with the bottom button,

How can I make these col's equal height with uneven content and `book` button stick at the bottom of the col's

[Fiddle without jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/nt6mgcpe/)

[Fiddle with jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/nt6mgcpe/1/)

Comment: Just a note; you *need* jQuery if you're planning on using Bootstrap, as many of the components require jQuery-specific functions to work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Jquery i set the height of the button relative to the divs. But you'll need a media query to keep it responsive:

```
if ($(window).width() >= 768){
        $(".btn-booking", this).each(function () {
            id = $(this).data('id');
            pos = highestBox - $("[data-id='" + id + "']").position().top;
            pos -= 2 * $(this).height();
            $("[data-id='" + id + "']").css("margin-top", pos);            
        });
    }
```

Here's a fiddle: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alezanatta/nt6mgcpe/2/)

Comment: Thanks, after some adjustment and adding `setinterval` function, i make it work, http://jsfiddle.net/nt6mgcpe/3/